# Office.context.mailbox.item.setSelectedDataAsync does not inserting content in body, if the email body is not in focus

Tags: office-js

I tried to add content into my email body using "Office.context.mailbox.item.setSelectedDataAsync".  content is adding fine if the body of the email is in focus.

platform: Macos
browser: chrome
outlook online

Comment: Did you ever found a fix for this? Having the same problem.

Comment: @Sylnois below answer worked for me. try that.

Answer (score 0):

to add content in body even  in out of focus use:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(content, {coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html, asyncContext: {}});
```

To add subject use:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.setAsync(subject, null, (result : Office.AsyncResult<void>) => {
 if (result.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                console.error(`Action failed with message ${result.error.message}`);
                return;
              }
            });
```